# Chaining pluck() and flatten() with lodash

Tags: javascript, lodash

This works, but how can I chain it?...

```
allWeeks = _.flatten(_.pluck(dates.months, 'weeks'))
allDays  = _.flatten(_.pluck(allWeeks, 'days'))
```

I've tried:

```
allDays = _.chain(dates.months).pluck('weeks').flatten().pluck('days').flatten()
```

And this:

```
allDays = _(dates.months).pluck('weeks').flatten().pluck('days').flatten()
```

Answer (score 44, accepted):

Instead of deleting this question out of sheer embarrassment, I will leave the answer here for any other poor schmuck out there wondering "why the heck isn't my lodash chain working?!":

> You must end the chain with `.value()`

so this:

```
allDays = _.chain(dates.months).pluck('weeks').flatten().pluck('days').flatten().value()
```

and this:

```
allDays = _(dates.months).pluck('weeks').flatten().pluck('days').flatten().value()
```

Comment: From one schmuck to another: Thank you.

Answer (score 5):

You have to know that starting for Lodash 4.0.0, _.pluck() is replaced by _.map()
so for example:

```
var objects = [{ 'a': 1 }, { 'a': 2 }];

// in 3.10.1
_.pluck(objects, 'a'); // → [1, 2]
_.map(objects, 'a'); // → [1, 2]

// in 4.0.0
_.map(objects, 'a'); // → [1, 2]
```

Comment: Good info, might be more appropriate as a comment

Comment: This is *definitely* useful as an answer.  The question is: how do you `chain` a `map`, to replace a chained `pluck`?

Comment: Chaining a map is the same as chaining a pluck was:
`_.chain(objects).map('a').value();`